# Facebook application published on a Facebook fan page... not facebook profile?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook profile of my own, and asociated to this Facebook profile I have a Facebook fan page,,, and I developed a Facebook application that now days is published on Facebook.

What I want is to asociate this Facebook App not to my profile but to my fan page... I mean,,, I know that so I can create a Facebook App or a Facebook Fan Page I've to have a Facebook profile account but I would like to know if I can asociate the Facebook App only to be visible throught the Page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is to make the application non-functional for other pages and users. You can do this by checking the POST variables (specifically fb_sig_page_id) to determine which Page you are on (or if you're on a Page at all). If the page ID doesn't match your page, just display a message.

Since applications automatically have Pages of their own created by Facebook, you can't prevent users from becoming fans/liking the application Page. This is one of the problems of the Facebook platform.

An alternative is to use the application Page as the official Facebook Page. This is what I've done with someecards (shameless plug). The application acts as the official presence on Facebook, so the official Page and the application are the same.

Comment: Thanks that what I was wondering... I'm just gonna create another Facebook profile...